# Unit Test case in Grails with mocking the methods

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, junit, mocking

I was trying to write a unit test case for the action 'passwordActive' in 'LoginController'. But i am not sure which all things to be mocked and how to do that.

```
    def passwordActive={
        log.error("Entering into Password Active")
        println "Password Active -- Params =  "+params

        String contextPath = request.contextPath
        String username = null              
        User user = null

    try{

            if (params.username != null && params.username.trim().length() > 0) {
            username = params.username
            user = User.findByUsername(username)
            }

            if (user == null) {
                log.error("USER not found.")                
                flash.errorLogin = "Username is incorrect"
                redirect(action:"auth") 
                return          
             }else if(user.password != params.password){
                log.error("USER password is wrong..")
                flash.errorLogin = "Please enter valid password.."
                redirect(action:"auth")
                return
             }else if (!user.active) {
                log.error("USER is inactive.")              
                flash.errorLogin = "User in Inactive"
                redirect(action:"auth") 
                return          
            }

            session["userid"] = user.id

            String userRole = user.authority.authority
            String url = contextPath + "/" + userRole           
            println "URL = "+url                
            redirect(url: url, method: 'post', params: params)      
            return  
       }
       catch(Exception e){
        println e.printStackTrace()
       }

    log.error("Exit into Password Active")

    }
```

i want to write a test case where username does not exist. in that case flash message should be having the message "username incorrect" and i can assert it.
Here what all things should be mocked and how to do that. Could you please explain the working with a small example (preferably related with above code so that it would be easy for me to understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing your own security implementation is a terribly bad idea. I suggest you take a look at how the Spring Security plugin does it for educational purposes, then just use that plugin - it is mature, flexible and easy to set up.

For said educational purposes, let's see how we could mock above code using an approach that is loosely along the lines of how Spring Security does it: You would move the user lookup into a service/bean as controllers aren't meant to contain any 'business' logic. Say something like this:

```
class UserProviderService {
    User findUser(String username) {
        User.findByUsername(username)
    }
}
```

In the controller you would injected it as a dependency (`def userProviderService`) on which you would then call your own function, e.g. `userProviderService.findUser(username)`. During normal operation Grails would inject your `UserProviderService` into the controller while in unit tests you can mock it however you like (e.g. `controller.userProviderService = [ findByUsername: { -> return null } ]` if you for example wanted to test the controller response for an unknown user.

Similar for password comparison you would use a `passwordService` that would implement password hashing, comparison and so on and you could mock its response before every test. Note that this stuff is again not trivial if you care about security and very easy to mess up so again: don't do it yourself!

The way you structure your code determines how easy or hard it will be to test it. Sure you could mess with `User.metaclass` and override methods left and right, but that approach usually proves very fragile. By splitting up your code you can make your life easier! How to structure your code so it is testable is definitely something you learn by experience so keep thinking about it!

Comment: i was trying to mock a method in service class as below. but its not working def userService
controller.userService=new UserService()

controller.userService=[passwordComplexityCheck:{def k->
        return true

    }]  Below is my service class                                                                                                                                                         class UserService {
          //required declaration 
          ........
      public boolean passwordComplexityCheck(String password) { return true} }

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does your actual method get called or are you getting some kind of exception (if so, what does the exception say?)